# Как вывести значения Map в View в Android

Tags: android, map

Всем привет. У меня есть `Map` в котором хранятся заголовки(key) и ссылки(value), как я могу передать их в `View`? как я понимаю `ArrayAdapter` не подходит.

```
private void printFavoritesList() {        
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.article, favoritesList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final ArrayList mData;

public MyAdapter(Map<String, String> map) {
    mData = new ArrayList();
    mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO implement you own logic with ID
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {
        result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_adapter_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        result = convertView;
    }

    Map.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

    // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(item.getKey());
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(item.getValue());

    return result;
}
}
```

**my_adapter_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

**Activity:**

```
public void showCinemas(HashMap<String, String> cinemas) {
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(cinemas);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```